# Is saying "I'm voting to reopen" not allowed?

Tags: discussion

I believe my question, [Will SCOTUS be forced to rule on birthright citizenship soon?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55341/will-scotus-be-forced-to-rule-on-birthright-citizenship-soon) was closed unreasonably: procedural aspects are explicitly on-topic, and there are, in fact, many questions on this site about issues other than "the current state of the law". I also left a comment explaining my vote to reopen.

However, my comment was deleted. Is there a reason for it? In contrast, someone else's "I'm voting to close" was left alone, even though that vote is over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was closed by five members of the community through the site's usual process. That means you can petition to have it reopened—it had received two votes to reopen as of this writing.

Leaving comments explaining why you're voting to reopen is allowed. I deleted a number of comments about trolling, including the mention of it in your comment (which would have seemed out of place given the other deletions). Feel free to leave another comment about why you think it should be reopened.